# How to transfer files to other system ,when system is blocked for any outside connection

Tags: ubuntu, file-transfer

My ubuntu 12 server is in a network and network is secured to block for making any outgoing connections, So I want a solution to configure any server configuration to allow me to send and access info to remote servers

My network is protected by watchdog/cyberom firewall.

What I needed is:   I am downloading a file to a remote server by accessing my local ubuntu server(above mentioned) having apache tomcat. So problem is if I put on downloading a large file from tomcat directory and if internet Fails, The file Get corrupted and download starts fresh again.

I want to resume a download from where it stopped.

So can anyone help me in setting any server for data transmission

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure I understand your question, but you can use wget with the **-c** flag to continue downloading a partial file:

In terminal:

```
wget -c http://file-to-download
```

Alternatively you could use a download manager like uGet or FreeDownloadManager to download the files in a way resistant to internet dropouts.